# P.J. Hilton notes requested

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, books

Does anybody here have the mimeographed notes *Homotopy theory and duality*, by P.J. Hilton, Cornell University, 1959 ?

I guess that those notes were never published online.

I believe that some topologist member here could have it. Thanks for a while.

Comment: Dear @Sigur: You may want to consider asking at the algtop-l mailing list. You may have better luck there.

Comment: @RicardoAndrade, thanks for attention and suggestion. Are you a member of that list?

Comment: Many topologists subscribe to that list; many more so than are likely to hang out at mathoverflow.

Comment: Is it possible to do a search on the list to know if someone asked that book before?

Comment: The list archives are [here](http://lists.lehigh.edu/pipermail/algtop-l/). However, they have no search function. A quick search through the dominant search engine revealed no reference to those notes in the mailing list, though.

Comment: @RicardoAndrade, thanks for introducing me to that list. I'll ask there.

Comment: Dear @Sigur: You are most welcome. If you decide to keep the present question, please make sure to report back on any findings.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the Cornell library has the original mimeographed notes.  You could probably get a copy via an interlibrary request.

Answer (score 2):

Hilton's lecture notes were published by [Gordon & Breach](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0198466) (1965). I guess many libraries will have it, and you can buy a copy [online](http://www.abebooks.com/book-search/title/homotopy-theory-duality/page-1/).

Answer (score 1):

I have a copy right here in my office.  If you need something specific, I'd be happy to scan in a few pages for you.

In addition, I should mention that if you're looking for a readable introduction homotopy that takes the point of view of Eckmann–Hilton like Hilton's book, I would highly recommend "Introduction to Homotopy Theory" by Martin Arkowitz. Arkowitz was one of Hilton's first doctoral students, and his book just came out a couple years ago.